# I need to run Apache2 Server & Websphere Application server together to run a java Project

Tags: apache2, websphere

I need to run Apache2 Server & Websphere Application server together to run a java Project.

Now the problem is By default Apache2 server runs on port:80 & in my virtual machine a system's process(kernel) is also running on port:80; so I have changed the port of Apache2 server in the 'http.conf' file.(Listen 88) & in the 'plugin_cfg.xml' also changed the port 88 under 'VirtualHostGroup'.After changed the port I was able to run the Apache server & hit the static part of the project but for that I need to mention the 'port number 88'('http://d-xdd537:88/wsa/') in the url & I can run the dynamic part also by using the port number of Websphere Application Server.But, I couldn't able to run both(Static + dynamic part of the project) at a time by using the url pattern "http://dxdd537/wsa/login.action". I have noticed that in 64 bit VM no System related tasks is running on port80 & when Apache2 is running on port:80 we are not facing all these issues & with the url mentioned the application is working fine; but for 32 bit machines as we can't stop port:80 so had to change the default port of Apache2 server & here comes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use port 88 in your URL at the client, you'll need to add *:88 host_alias to the "default_host" virtualhost in the Application Server config (Environment > Virtual Hosts)

Note, unlike most changes in WAS, this does require a restart.

Comment: I have tried to add '88 ports' under the path "Application servers > server1 > Ports" in the Admin console of WAS but it's behaving the same.Is it what you were suggesting? Can you please elaborate your suggestion?

Comment: Enviromment -> Virtual Hosts